# Template class, static function call -> is this elegant?

Tags: c++

I have a template class with all functions declared as static.

```
template <class T>
class Cache {

private:
    Cache() {}
    static std::map<std::string, std::string> c_files;

public:

    ~Cache() {}

    template<class T> static void add(T const &file, std::string id) {
        return;
    }
    //... here are some other functions

    static void init() {
         // do some initialization
    }
}
```

Normally I would call it like:

```
Cache<BITMAP*>::add(my_bitmap, "my_identifier");
```

which works fine.

But the thing is, I need to do some one-time initialization when my app starts. (checking for cached files on the HDD, push them into the map).

At the moment I'm using a "fake" call like:

```
Cache<bool>::update();
```

which I think is really a mess.

Now, is this messy call okay, or is it complete against some programming standards? How would you solve that problem?

Comment: Without knowing the original problem you want to solve with the solution you have, one possible "solution" that comes to mind is the [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: Static function calls on templated classes are nothing bad. Also i dont get, why one call to update is a mess.
I would try to isolate the problem into one class, without static functions and global state.Sure you could create a global instance of you class and do all the initilisation in the constructor, than all the initilisation would be done on progamm start, but global state is a bad thing for many reasons.
I would do all the initilisation in the constructor and create a local instance. If you create the instance early in you main you can get similar behaviour.